# What is the proper way to render an async function?

Tags: javascript, polymer, frontend, render, lit-element

I have a function that fetches an object and returns a boolean from a check on the said object.

I need this boolean to decide what HTML should be the output of my render() function. When the function that checks the fetched object is called in my render() function, it always returns "undefined", as it always evaluates to true.

How should I proceed to output the correct value in proper timing? Thank you.

```
    async isGreenlisted() {
        return fetch(`${WEB_SERVICE_URL}/v2/banners/${this.viewId}`)
            .then(res => {
                for (let list in res) {
                    if (res[list].isDisplayed && list === "green") {
                        console.log("green true");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            });
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <style>
                paper-button {
                    color: blue;
                }
            </style>
            <div>
                ${this.isGreenlisted()
            ? html`
                            <paper-button raised @click="${this._onClick}">Disable Powered By</paper-button>
                      `
            : html`
                            <paper-button raised @click="${this._onClick}">Enable Powered By</paper-button>
                      `}
            </div>
        `;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a state for that purpose.

Comment: `async` need to be used with `await`. In your case, you need to wait the fetch function to render the element. And, i thing that the idea of a state suggested by @GabrielLMartinez is a good approach.

Comment: In the for loop there is a ```return html``;``` after the `if` statement. Is this intended? It'll stop the loop at the first iteration and you're not actually rendering the returned template.

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes Yes, my bad, i edited it out. What do you mean by not returning the template?

Comment: I believe that the idea on the @Umbo answer is the way, Show a loading state until the fetch is running.

Comment: @Jocarol Never mind, I meant that the ```html`` ``` you were returning wouldn't be rendered but instead just evaluated as boolean expression in the ternary operator. Now makes more sense :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`isGreenlisted()` returns a `Promise` so in the ternary operator you're essentially evaluating the promise itself instead of the value it will resolve to, and since class instances are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), the first template is always shown.

You should instead wait for the result of the promise, for example by using `lit-html`'s [`until` directive](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#until):

```js
import {until} from 'lit-html/directives/until';

render() {
  return html`
  ${until(
    this.isGreenlisted().then(res => res
      ? html`True`
      : html`False`),
    html`Loading...`,
  )}
  `;
}
```

Comment: You saved me brother. From endless hair pulling and twisting my code